# Post method not working when I use postman for run API In laravel 5.1 API

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Controller code: `public function xyz(){echo 'hello';}`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function(){Route::post('apiregstration','APIcontroller@xyz');});
```

I use laravel 5.1 and want to create API with post method but it not work ,
GET method work fine

Comment: What "doesn't work" exactly? What's the expected behavior vs what's actually happening? We can't understand what's going on with just that code, so please update your question and include as much details as you can.

Comment: postman return error 404 error with html code error

Answer (score 0):

If get is work but post not working, maybe you should try to run `php artisan route:clear`run to clear route caches.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a typo in your snippet (which I'm assuming is coming directly from your source).

Try changing

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::post('apiregstration','APIcontroller@xyz');
});
```

To

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::post('apiregistration','APIcontroller@xyz');
});
```

I'm assuming you meant `'apiregistration'` and not `'apiregstration'`.

There is not much we can assume or test or check with the info you provided.
If the error doesn't go away, try adding a bit more of your code in the question so we can help.